# How to reset you-tube video after playing to stop recommadations

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I have one scenario. I am playing a you-tube video in iframe using embed code

```
<iframe width="940" height="552" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ucXTSAUH2UE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Now if we play video and when video completes it shows suggestion videos at end. Can someone suggest me how i can stop this suggestion and reset my you-tube video again.

Comment: Add `&rel=0` to the end of the URL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can simply append **`?rel=0`** to the end of the YouTube URL to disable related videos at the end of the video.

That is,

Replace

```
<iframe width="940" height="552" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ucXTSAUH2UE" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

with

```
<iframe width="940" height="552" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ucXTSAUH2UE?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: I tried it that time but its was throwing some error. Thanks for that

Comment: As of 2023, rel is deprected